# Замена параметров URL на ЧПУ в разном порядке, с отсутствием или наличием некоторых параметров

Tags: yii2

Имеется адрес с несколькими параметрами вида:

website.ru/page?id=12&tag=novosti

Необходимо, чтобы адрес преобразовался в: website.ru/page/id/12/tag/novosti
или в website.ru/page/tag/novosti/id/12 или в 
website.ru/page/tag/12 и т.д. в зависимости от того, в каком порядке параметры стоят. Есть ли способ как-то переделать автозамену, чтобы не писать каждое правило под каждый вид урлы? Дело в том, что параметров может быть много (до 5) и, соответственно, и комбинаций их тоже может быть много. Может быть адрес без id или без tag, например.

Код UrlManager:

```
    'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [  
            '/page/id/<id:\d+>' => '/page/',
            '/page/tag/<tag:\w+>' => '/page/',
            '/page/id/<id:\d+>/tag/<tag:\w+>' => '/page/'


 ]
```

Подскажите, в какую сторону копать? Можно ли указать UrlManager что-то такое: "id=12" просто меняй на /id/12 и добавляй к имеющемуся адресу.
Спасибо!

Comment: Так не бывает. Надо конкретно определиться с параметрами и дать им приоритет. Если некоторых параметров может не быть, зачем тогда их пихать в ЧПУ? Передать их параметрами &p=v&p2=v2 и id там явно лишнее, 12 это и есть id.

Comment: Понял, значит, значит, надо пересмотреть саму идею генерации урл. Спасибо.